# PulseAudio Audio Devices Disappear After Reboot, Or Maybe Not

Tags: linux-mint, pulseaudio, usb-audio

Half the time after a reboot the USB Behringer U-Control UCA202 does not show as an input or output device in the PulseAudio Volume Control.

The system is running Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.3. The UCA202 is Device-2:

```
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:02c8 
           Device-2: Texas Instruments PCM2902 Audio Codec type: USB 
           driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus ID: 1-3:36 chip ID: 08bb:2902
```

The pactl list outputs:

```
pactl list short sources
0   alsa_input.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
2   bluez_sink.C0_7A_CC_02_00_F5.a2dp_sink.monitor  module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING

pactl list short sinks
1   bluez_sink.C0_7A_CC_02_00_F5.a2dp_sink  module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
```

I would guess that a device scan is failing - don't have any idea to fix this.

Comment: Debug by looking at the layers: First the kernel layer (`dmesg` output is your first stop, compare a boot with device vs. one without, note error messages. Don't `grep`), then the ALSA layer, finally the Pulseaudio layer. My money is on the kernel layer.

Comment: dirkt, thanks, I found a mountain of syncthing UFW BLOCK messages; sudo ufw allow syncthing fixed that; continuing on kernel layer.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to have fixed this is adding the following to the end of /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
load-module module-detect
```

The idea to try the above came from a reference to a pactl command to get a sink loaded (ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1318285/pulseaudio-module-alsa-sink-cannot-be-loaded-automatically-by-module-udev-de). This is odd as the command is depreciated.

```
pactl load-module module-detect
```

I haven't found a better solution but for the present it solves the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I updated it as requested.